# How to decode Norwegian or any special character in a xml to display it in TextView

Tags: ios, xml, ipad, nsstring, special-characters

I am dealing with strings in my project where in i send some data (string) to a service and the service responses me XML with some data (String).Earlier i used to face probs while sending special charcters like &,",',<,>,$,%,(,) etc in the string.

Then i encoded the string before sending as below:

```
NSString *str=@"Â£&@)(;:/-.,?!'"[]{}#%^*+=Â¥$â¬><~||_~<.,?!'m"";
NSString *stringToSend=[str stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

then data sent is as below:
 "**%C2%A3%26%40%29%28%3B%3A%2F-.%2C%3F%21%27%22%5B%5D%7B%7D%23%25%5E%2A%2B%3D%C2%A5%24%E2%82%AC%3E%3C~%7C%7C_~%3C.%2C%3F%21%27m%22**"

then the server handles the data as required.

While receving the data from server i do decoding as below:

```
NSString *strReceived=@"%C2%A3%26%40%29%28%3B%3A%2F-.%2C%3F%21%27%22%5B%5D%7B%7D%23%25%5E%2A%2B%3D%C2%A5%24%E2%82%AC%3E%3C~%7C%7C_~%3C.%2C%3F%21%27m%22";
NSString *str=[str stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

then data received is :**Â£&@)(;:/-.,?!'"[]{}#%^*+=Â¥$â¬><~||_~<.,?!'m"** as expected.

**PROBLEM/ISSUE**

Now if my string contains norwegian characters like å,ø,Ø,æ,etc.
the string in response contains (%E5 for å) (%E6 for æ)and (%D8 for Ø)and (%F8 for ø).

I get the string as invalid after ececution of "**stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding**".

Can some one suggest how to handle all the charcters received in the xml and parse them perfectly.Plz help with ur inputs...

Tnx in advance.

Comment: What do you mean "get the string as invalid"?  You mean it is nil?  Or contains incorrect characters?

Comment: The end string i get is empty.But while debugging if i place my mouse on the string after the said step it shows invalid...What i guess is stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding is not able to process such characters...

Comment: Don't rely on that.  Always use the debugger command "po" to print out the object description.  Often times the mouseover shows invalid, but the po command will show something else.  Google indicates that UTF-8 and norwegian characters often don't get along.  The odd thing, is that I find all of your escape codes to be UTF-16 format.

Comment: tnx for ur efforts...How could u figure out those are UTF-16 format..plz xplain i wanted to learn and helps me

Comment: Well, you can search unicode characters here -> http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm and it will give you a breakdown of how they are formatted in various byte encodings.

Comment: Finally my question goes to beginning..How can  decode & encode the norwegian characters like  %D8,%F8,%E6,%E5  etc.Is there any method on NSString or any provision by sdk.People speak abt Html entities and are providing few category methods on NSString.I tried integrating those methods into my NSString category... even dat didn't help..plz help